# How to apply a plugin to all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm currently using http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/ as a plugin and I want to do the following:

```
    $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'left',
                }
            );

            $('#carousel-demo2').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'right',
                }
            );

            $('#carousel-demo3').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'left',
                }
            );
            $('#carousel-demo4').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'right',
                }
            );
```

This is the code I use to initiate the plugin and it works. However, I want when one of the lists is hovered, all of them to start moving and not just the one I am hovering. What I tried to do:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $('ul').mouseover(function() 
        {
            $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: true,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'left',
                }
            );

            $('#carousel-demo2').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: true,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'right',
                }
            );

            $('#carousel-demo3').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: true,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'left',
                }
            );
            $('#carousel-demo4').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: true,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'right',
                }
            );
        });

        $('ul').mouseleave(function() 
        {
            $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'left',
                }
            );

            $('#carousel-demo2').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'right',
                }
            );

            $('#carousel-demo3').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'left',
                }
            );
            $('#carousel-demo4').scrollingCarousel
            (
                {
                    autoScroll: false,
                    autoScrollDirection: 'right',
                }
            );
        });
```

But this does not work. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `.hover()` function?

```
$( "ul" ).hover(function() {
 // add functions here
});
```

Comment: Isn't it the same thing? My problem is that the code fully bugs out when I try to do what I showed.

Comment: It's shorthand for mouseenter and mouseleave... But you only want to call it the first time right? So maybe try it but incorporate a counter or a boolean. Something like; var counter = 0; $('ul').hover(function() {counter+=1; if (counter!=1){return false;}else{//do this}});

Answer (score 0):

Give all your `li` a class, for example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="demo"></li>
    <li class="demo"></li>
    <li class="demo"></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.demo').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('.demo').scrollingCarousel
     (
         {
             autoScroll: true,
             autoScrollDirection: 'left',
         }
     );
});
```

Comment: Does not work, the code just bugs out, and works only on 1 pair (those who need to go right for e.g. won't work). At the same time when I hover one side, the other LI bugs out and works in one place only.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?